# Reflection GetMethod with a type paramenter

Tags: c#, reflection, types, getmethod

The following line is not running properly, and I'm not sure why. The Error:
System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: parameters do not match signature

And the line of code in question:

```
typeof(Resources).GetMethod("LoadAll", new Type[] { typeof(System.String), typeof(System.Type)});
```

Displaying all functions of the Resources class shows:

```
UnityEngine.Object[] FindObjectsOfTypeAll(System.Type)
T[] FindObjectsOfTypeAll[T]()
UnityEngine.Object Load(System.String)
T Load[T](System.String)
UnityEngine.Object Load(System.String, System.Type)
UnityEngine.ResourceRequest LoadAsync(System.String)
UnityEngine.ResourceRequest LoadAsync[T](System.String)
UnityEngine.ResourceRequest LoadAsync(System.String, System.Type)
UnityEngine.Object[] LoadAll(System.String, System.Type)
UnityEngine.Object[] LoadAll(System.String)
T[] LoadAll[T](System.String)
UnityEngine.Object GetBuiltinResource(System.Type, System.String)
T GetBuiltinResource[T](System.String)
Void UnloadAsset(UnityEngine.Object)
UnityEngine.AsyncOperation UnloadUnusedAssets()
Boolean Equals(System.Object)
Int32 GetHashCode()
System.Type GetType()
System.String ToString()
System.Reflection.MethodInfo[]
```

I'm trying to match UnityEngine.Object[] LoadAll(System.String, System.Type). Any thoughts on what may be the issue?

Bonus if you can make a line that returns a methodinfo object for "T[] LoadAllT", specific to a given type.

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to get an instance level method while the LoadAll is static. Try this one.
`typeof(Resources).GetMethod("LoadAll", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static, 
new Type[] { typeof(System.String), typeof(System.Type)},
null
);`

Comment: Had to add the a binder, I assumed the default. But it doesn't find the method. Here's the line I used: `return typeof(Resources).GetMethod("LoadAll", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(System.String), typeof(System.Type) }, null);`

Comment: I am mistaken, that line of code appears to work, my test just seemed to have failed... If you copy down I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ambiguous match found when using reflection to find Generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52965405/ambiguous-match-found-when-using-reflection-to-find-generic-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to get an instance level method while the LoadAll is static.

Try this one:

```
typeof(Resources).GetMethod("LoadAll", 
                            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static,   
                            new Type[] { typeof(System.String),typeof(System.Type)},
                             null);
```