# Ambiguous match found when using reflection to find Generic method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, generic-method

I'm using reflection to find the generic method for Newtonsoft `JsonConvert.DeserializedObject<T>` but am finding that it's returning an ambiguous match for the non-generic version `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, here is the code which tries to get the generic method:

```
return typeof(JsonConvert).GetMethod("DeserializeObject", new Type[] { typeof(string) }).MakeGenericMethod(genericType);
```

I've specified that I want the method which takes a `string` as its only argument but both the generic and non-generic version have matching parameter lists, and I receive the ambiguous match error.

Is it possible to to get the generic version using `GetMethod` in this way? I know I can use Linq and `GetMethods()` to find it e.g:

```
var method = typeof(JsonConvert).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(
            x => x.Name.Equals("DeserializeObject", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            x.IsGenericMethod && x.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
            x.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(string));
```

But this is a bit cumbersome, there must be a better way.

Comment: @DavidG - Hmm.. isn't the generic type passed in here `MakeGenericMethod(genericType);` ?

Comment: Sorry, misspoke in that comment. What is actually happening though is `GetMethod` cannot choose between `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string)`. I think you are stuck with the Linq method here.

Comment: @DavidG - Yeah i was hoping there was some way to specify I want the generic version in `GetMethod()` but I guess not, thanks anyway!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reflection GetMethod with a type paramenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876247/reflection-getmethod-with-a-type-paramenter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive from `Binder` class

```
class MyBinder : Binder
{
    public override MethodBase SelectMethod(BindingFlags bindingAttr, MethodBase[] match, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {          
        return match.First(m => m.IsGenericMethod);
    }

    #region not implemented
    public override MethodBase BindToMethod(BindingFlags bindingAttr, MethodBase[] match, ref object[] args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, string[] names, out object state) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override FieldInfo BindToField(BindingFlags bindingAttr, FieldInfo[] match, object value, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override PropertyInfo SelectProperty(BindingFlags bindingAttr, PropertyInfo[] match, Type returnType, Type[] indexes, ParameterModifier[] modifiers) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override object ChangeType(object value, Type type, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override void ReorderArgumentArray(ref object[] args, object state) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    #endregion
}
```

Usage:

```
var method = typeof(JsonConvert).GetMethod("DeserializeObject",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
    new MyBinder(),
    new[] {typeof(string)},
    null);
```

In your case `MyBinder` will receive two candidates in `SelectMethod`

```
public static object DeserializeObject(string value)
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string value)
```

Code above will select first generic method

Comment: Really useful! though probably overkill in my case, but will accept as the answer :)

Comment: Nice, though this is basically pretty similar to the original Linq, nonetheless useful to know.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want this:

```
var method = typeof(JsonConvert).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(
    x => x.Name.Equals("DeserializeObject", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    x.IsGenericMethod && x.GetParameters().Length == 1)
    ?.MakeGenericMethod(genericType);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have in the OP - minus the param type check, I'm looking for a way to do it with `GetMethod()`

Comment: I don´t see exactly this one (4th line is different)

Comment: Ok, it's a subtle tweak but my point is, it's the same solution I already have in the OP which works, but id like to do it with `GetMethod()` if at all possible.

Comment: @DGibbs there is no way using `GetMethod`, you have to use `GetMethods` and filter afterwards.

Comment: updated with genericType so this one will give you `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<genericType>(string)`

Answer (score 5):

There are `GetMethod` methods which do distinguish between generic and non-generic methods; an example is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=net-5.0#system-type-getmethod(system-string-system-int32-system-type())) with the integer parameter `genericParamCount`:

> Searches for the specified public method whose parameters match the specified generic parameter count and argument types.

The following code:

```
var genericMethod = typeof(JsonConvert)
    .GetMethod("DeserializeObject", 1, new Type[] { typeof(string) })
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
var otherMethod = typeof(JsonConvert)
    .GetMethod("DeserializeObject", 0, new Type[] { typeof(string) });
Console.WriteLine(genericMethod);
Console.WriteLine(otherMethod);
```

will print

```
System.String DeserializeObject[String](System.String)
System.Object DeserializeObject(System.String)
```

so this is perhaps the shortest solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`Type.GetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.getmethod?view=netstandard-1.6) doesn't allow you to specify the generic type meaning that this code:

```
var method = typeof(JsonConvert).GetMethod("DeserializeObject", new[] { typeof(string)})
```

is trying to resolve between the 2 matching methods `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string)`.

Unfortunately you are stuck with the Linq option to do this.